# Integral of a continuous family of i.i.d bernoulli random variables

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes, poisson-process

Let $F(t) \sim \operatorname{Ber}(p)$ for every $t \in [0,1]$. Let $X = \int_0^1 F(t)\,dt$. $X$ is of course itself a random variable.

Questions:

- Does $X$ exist?
- If so, what is the distribution of $X$? I think that $\Pr[X = p] = 1$, because if we approximate $X$ as $Y$ where $Y = \sum_{i=0}^N F(t+iN^{-1})N^{-1}$ then $\operatorname{Var}\left( Y\right) \\= \sum_{i=0}^N \operatorname{Var}\left( F(t+iN^{-1})N^{-1}\right)\\=N^{-2} \sum_{i=0}^N \operatorname{Var}\left( F(t+iN^{-1})\right)\\=N^{-2}(N+1)p(1-p) \to 0 \text{ as }N\to \infty$

Comment: Your first paragraph is ambiguous: could you please edit it to include proper quantifiers and some description of the context?

Comment: @whuber hopefully I've addressed that with my edit. Please tell me if it's still unclear

Comment: Thank you--that helps a lot.  It is of interest that your mathematical description differs substantially from the English description.  That might cause many people to ask for further clarification.  Food for thought: let $F$ be the constant function $t\to 1$ with probability $p\in(0,1)$ and otherwise let it be the zero function.  All your assumptions hold for this $F$ (including the implicit one that it be integrable a.s.), yet $\Pr(X=pT)=0$. That leads me to suspect your mathematical description might not be expressing the problem you actually have.

Comment: @whuber I mean that $F(t)$ is a Bernoulli random variable for every $t$. I'll edit the question

Comment: In my example, $F(t)$ indeed is a Bernoulli random variable for each $t$.  Perhaps you should clearly indicate what you mean by a "random function."  It will be important that your definition imply that $X$ actually exists almost surely!

Comment: @whuber Sorry for bothering you again. Would it make sense to say that $\Pr[F(t) = 1] = p$ and $\Pr[F(t) = 0] = 1 - p$ for all $t$? So by a random function, I mean something like a binomial random variable where each trial occurs continuously instead of discretely.

Comment: Once again, my example has all those properties. Do you think you could restate your question in nontechnical terms?  Is it perhaps motivated by a statistical analysis you are performing, or a machine learning problem that you could share?

Comment: @whuber Sorry; if you're still not satisfied, I'll delete the question. What I mean is that there is a probability distribution over functions from $[0,T]$ to $\{0,1\}$ that $F$ could be. That distribution is uniform, so $F$ could take on any value in $\{0,1\} ^ {\mathbb [0,1]}$ with equal probability. Given that, $X = \int_0^T F(t)\, dt$ is a random variable. The question is what is the pdf of $X$? I'm not sure if it's possible to have a uniform distribution over $\{0,1\}^{[0,T]}$. Does that make sense?

Comment: It makes sense, but unfortunately such a mathematical object does not exist, at least not without additional restrictions.  The first problem is defining a measure on the space of such functions for which you can make any sense of "uniform".  The second one is that most such functions will not be integrable and so $X$ will be undefined: it is not a random variable.  You appear to be interested in a *continuous time stochastic process*--there's a subject you ought to investigate further.

Comment: @whuber I just wanted to leave a comment stating that my summary of what $F$ is was wrong, and I have completely rewritten the question.

Comment: Thank you.  The question of the existence of $X$ concerns whether it makes sense to integrate a function whose values are themselves random variables, rather than numbers.  I suspect you are hoping that would be the same as drawing a random value (equal to $0$ or $1$) independently for every $t$, which would give you a real-valued function, and integrating it to give a value of $X$  Unfortunately, that function has zero chance of having an integral in any sense.

Comment: To define a random function $Z:T\times\Omega\to\mathscr{Z}$ you must specify a consistent family of finite-dimensional distributions. That is, for any $t_1,\dots,t_k\in T$, you must provide the distribution of the random vector $(Z(t_1),\dots,Z(t_k))$, and check the consistency (in the sense of Kolmogorov's Theorem) of the provided family.

Comment: @Zen Are you saying that $F$ is not a well-defined random function, or are you referring to the discussion I had with whuber above?

Comment: @Zen Those distributions have already been given through the implicit understanding that $F(t)$ and $F(s)$ are independent for $s\ne t$.  Thus we have a well-defined random function--but it's almost surely not integrable.  Perhaps the point of your comment is that additional restrictions (which could be phrased in terms of the finite distributions, which in turn amount to imposing dependencies among the $F(t)$) are needed in order for $X$ to be defined.

Comment: The more explicit he puts it, the better. Also, considering a fine enough $t_1,\dots,t_k\in[0,T]$, he would figure out that (a.s) the realizations of this random function are not integrable.